# Are there languages with more rigid word order than English?

Tags: word-order

English is sometimes said to not rely on [free word order](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/298/how-do-languages-manage-to-make-sense-with-a-free-word-order), and instead have a "strict" word order. But I can find all kinds of cases where word order is still free in English:

> I walked *quickly* over to the tree.
> I walked over to the tree *quickly*.
> I *quickly* walked over to the tree.

In English, noun phrases appear to *always* have the adjectives/modifiers *preceding* the main noun (but maybe there are cases that break this mold, not sure), so they are more strict:

> The big red car.

You can also have separated / phrasal verbs in many ways in a sentence.

Are there any languages which have a super strict word order, like 1 way of saying each thing, instead of many? If not, why not? If so, what are some examples?

I am wondering if it would be possible to construct a conlang with sentences something like `modifiers-verb-modifiers-noun-modifiers-verb-modifiers-noun-etc.` sort of thing, so modifiers always precede the noun or verb, and there are no prepositions. But wondering if that would be too "rigid", so looking for inspiration of how other languages handle this sort of situation.